# Android, TabLayout (tabhost), switching tabs disables edittext on second tab. How do I prevent this?

Tags: android, keyboard, focus, android-edittext, android-tabhost

I have a tablayout that consists of two tabs that are each its own activity, so three activities, one tab, two content.

Both of the two content activities consist of a button and one edittext field.

When I load up, the first activity shows, and I am able to click on the edittext field (which is highlighted in yellow) and the keyboard comes up. When I switch to the second tab, the edittext which is not highlighted in yellow, does not allow me to select it to bring up the keyboard.

If I switch back to the first tab after this point then back to the second, I am able to use the keyboard on both, and it works for the duration of the app.

I don't expect first time uses to play around and figure that out.

My question is, how would I be able to have the keyboard work on the first occurrence of the second tab?

If you need any code let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out in the layouts, when you create an edittext field, there was something in the XML that said something like

```
<requestfocus />
```

And by removing that it fixed it, on the second tab.

I don't know why that fixed it however.